# man in asylum insists everyone is conspiring against him; "the one they call mother" says he's just paranoid

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story as part of anthology compilation.

In the story, the main character, a man, is convinced that all of the people in his life are part of a conspiracy. He is in an asylum as a result. He addresses his mother as 'the one they call mother'.

His mother tries to convince him that he is paranoid and none of the conspiracy he believes exists. The twist at the end comes when it is confirmed that his mother is not actually his mother, and the main character is indeed the centre of a belligerent conspiracy.

Hopefully someone will recall the story, its author and the anthology that I might have been reading.

Comment: Are you sure it was his *mother*, not his *wife*? Except for that discrepancy it sounds a lot like Heinlein's "They" which you can read here: https://archive.org/stream/Unknown_v04n06_1941-04_PDF_unz.org#page/n83/mode/2up

Comment: Heinlein's "They" has appeared in these compilations: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?40871

Comment: Wow, amazing site! It was his wife rather than his mother, I got that part wrong. Many Thanks all.

Comment: So that was the right story?

Comment: yes, it is the right story